# How do I make 2 hour windows using data thats all 1 hour windows

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have data that looks like this:

Datetime      Price

[image: g]

and was just wondering how about I would turn them into 2 hour windows instead and use the average of the price of the two

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us do `resample` with `2h` freq

```
df['Datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Datetime'], dayfirst=True)
df.resample('2h', on='Datetime', origin='start')['Price'].mean()
```